# Erro ao chamar os dados de uma lista para uma tela de cadastro

Tags: android, listview, netbeans

Desde já Agradeço a compreensão de todos pois não sou muito experiente.Estou com um erro ao carregar os dados do cliente de uma lista quero que, ao clicar no adicionar cliente, venho o nome do cliente no campo cliente e assim com vendedor e produto. Porém quando eu clico no botão adicionar cliente ele abre a tela de lista, dou um onClickListner na linha do cliente e vem a tela do pedido sem o nome do cliente no campo cliente

[image: Desde já Agradeço a compreensão de todos pois não sou muito experiente.Estou com um erro ao carregar os dados do cliente de uma lista quero que, ao clicar no adicionar cliente, venho o nome do cliente no campo cliente e assim com vendedor e produto. Porém quando eu clico no botão adicionar cliente ele abre a tela de lista, dou um onClickListner na linha do cliente e vem a tela do pedido sem o nome do cliente no campo cliente<code>insira o código aqui</code>]

Código da tela do cadastro de pedido:

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import br.gestaoBd.BancoDeDados.PedidoDao;
 import br.gestaoBd.BancoDeDados.PedidoItensDao;
 import br.gestaoBd.Beans.Pedido;
 import br.gestaoBd.Beans.ItemDoPedido;
 import java.text.NumberFormat;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Locale;

 public class CadPedido extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener, OnItemClickListener {

static Pedido pedido;
static ArrayList<ItemDoPedido> itensDoPedido;
EditText ed1Id, ed1Cliente, ed1Vendedor, ed1Data;
PedidoDao pedDao;
ListView lista; 



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.cad_pedido);
    ed1Id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEd1Id);
    ed1Cliente = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEd1Cliente);
    ed1Vendedor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEd1Vendedor);
    ed1Data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEd1Data);

    lista= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    Button btAdicionarCliente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btAdicionarCliente);
    btAdicionarCliente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(CadPedido.this,
                    ListClientes.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Button btAdicionarVendedor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btAdicionarVendedor);
    btAdicionarVendedor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(CadPedido.this,
                    ListVendedor.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }); 

    Button btAdicionarProduto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btAdicionarProduto);
    btAdicionarProduto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setClass(CadPedido.this,
                    ListProdutos.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

public static Pedido getPedido() {
    if (pedido == null) {
        pedido = new Pedido();
    }
    return pedido;
}

public static ArrayList<ItemDoPedido> getItensDoPedido() {
    if (itensDoPedido == null) {
        Log.i("AULA", "cRIOU ITENS DO PEDIDO");
        itensDoPedido = new ArrayList<ItemDoPedido>();
    }
    return itensDoPedido;
}

public static double getTotal() {
    double total = 0.00;
    Log.i("AULA", "itens adiconados =" + getItensDoPedido().size());
    for (ItemDoPedido it : getItensDoPedido()) {
        total += it.getQuantidade() * it.getValorUnitario();
        Log.i("AULA", String.valueOf(total));
    }
    return total;
}

public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //Deseja excluir? = sim
    getItensDoPedido().remove(position);
    return true;
}

public void cancelar() {
    itensDoPedido = null;
    pedido = null;
    finish();
}

public void gravar() {
    PedidoDao pd = new PedidoDao();
    pd.inserirPedido(getPedido());

    PedidoItensDao pid = new PedidoItensDao();
    for (ItemDoPedido it : getItensDoPedido()) {
        it.setPedido(getPedido());
        pid.inserirPedidoItens(it);
    }
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 


} 

}
```

Código da tela de lista de clientes

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import br.gestaoBd.BancoDeDados.ClienteDao;
 import br.gestaoBd.Beans.Cliente;
 import br.gestaoBd.listaadapters.ClienteAdapter;
 import java.util.ArrayList;


 public class ListClientes extends Activity implements  AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

ListView lista;
ArrayList<Cliente> clientes;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_clientes);

    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    lista.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    atualizar(null);
}

public void atualizar(View view) {
    ClienteDao cliDao = new ClienteDao();

    clientes = cliDao.getListagem();
    lista.setAdapter(new ClienteAdapter(getBaseContext(), clientes));

}

public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent cadClienteIntent = new Intent(this, CadCliente.class);
    cadClienteIntent.putExtra("Cliente", clientes.get(position));
    startActivity(cadClienteIntent);
    return true;
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
    Intent cadPedidoIntent = new Intent(this, CadPedido.class);
    cadPedidoIntent.putExtra("Cliente", clientes.get(position));
    startActivity(cadPedidoIntent);


}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No botão btAdicionarCliente 
vc deve usar!

```
public class CadPedido extends Activity implements

private int RETURN_TELA_CLIENTE = 1;


//Evento OnClick
startActivityForResult( intent, RETURN_TELA_CLIENTE);
```

E na sua CadPedido vc deve sobrescrever o metodo.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == RETURN_TELA_CLIENTE) {
     /// pegar o retorno
}
```

}

Obs: Não use abreviações: tipo, "Cad..."

Segure REF oficial Developers..
http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: Eu fiz exatamente como tu recomendou e continua a mesma coisa.. @Eudes